# how to read data blocks and store them in database?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Hi there I have problem in reading a data block in oracle form builder.
I have one data block that some of their fields are come from database but there is 2 (columns)field that i need to read them manually and store them on the database(we have several row!),please help me how I can read each line  and insert them on database.
I use oracle form builder ver 6i.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write code like this in Forms:

```
GO_BLOCK('myblock');
FIRST_RECORD;
LOOP
  INSERT INTO my_table (col) VALUES (:myblock.item1);
  EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD='TRUE';
  NEXT_RECORD;
END LOOP;
```